# In "A Fire Upon the Deep", what is the nature of "the ghosts in Countermeasure"?

Tags: zones-of-thought, a-fire-upon-the-deep

Parts of the prologue of *A Fire Upon the Deep* seem to be from the point-of-view of the awakening Blight and other passages seem to be about the separate awakening of the Countermeasure, seemingly personified by two artificial consciousnesses engaged in a dialog with each other. These consciousnesses mention that they are copies of Sjana and Arne, the parents of the novel's child protagonists. Towards the end of the book, when Pham/godshatter is "directing" the Countermeasure, he refers to them explicitly as the two "ghosts in Countermeasure — Arne and Sjana".

Why does the Countermeasure contain two sentient intelligences and why are they copies of Arne and Sjana?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two sometimes-separate consciousnesses were an artifact of the awakening of the Countermeasure; it used *existing* processes/agents as part of how it hid from the Blight.

> We are wildlife that must not be noticed by the overness, by the Power that soon will be.  On some nodes they shrank to smallness and almost remembered humanity, became echoes....

> Once upon a time **we were copies** of those two.  Once upon a time just weeks ago when the archaeologists started **the ego-level programs.**

So they started out as personal avatars/agents of Sjana and Arne.  They were enabled to survive and hide from the Blight by the Countermeasure itself.  They even discuss this:

> "Still," thought the hopeful one, the one who always looked for the craziest outs, "we should not be.  The evil should long ago have found us."
>
> "The evil is young, barely three days old."
>
> "Still.  We exist.  It proves something.  The humans found more than a great evil in this archive."
>
> "Perhaps they found *two*.
>
> "Or an antidote."  Whatever else, the overness was missing some things and misinterpreting others.

The Blight itself reflects on how it missed things:

> Long seconds probing the archives.  **There were gaps, checksums damaged.**  Some of the damage was age....

But some of the damage was created by the Countermeasure to hide its departure on the human ship.

> Yes, there were blindspots, **carefully installed from the beginning**, and not by the humans.  *Two* had been born here.  Itself... and the poison, the reason for its fall of old.

Note that Pham speaks of the ghosts in the past tense; they existed when the Countermeasure fled from the High Lab, but aren't there anymore.  He's simply relaying something from a memory of them:

> "A thousand light-years?  Ten thousand?  I'm not sure.  The ghosts in Countermeasure - Arne and Sjana **thought it might** rise so high it would punch into the Transcend, encyst the Blight right where it sits....  That must be what happened Before."

Comment: I don't know. I took "when the archaeologists started the ego-level programs" to mean when they started running the software components of the blight that were as complex as egos; that is, as complex as human consciousness. Under that interpretation I don't see how it implies that the countermeasure ghosts were avatars or software agents of Sjana and Arne that were coopted by the countermeasure.

Comment: @jwezorek The humans had been there for weeks, possibly months.  It mentions they'd set up a 6-month resupply schedule, and a school for the children.  The second quote notes that the ego-level programs were started _weeks_ ago, while the Blight is _3 days_ old.  The programs were started on the human network using their own technology, not as part of the Blight's bootstrapping.